# Android connect to database

Tags: java, android, mysql, android-studio, phpmyadmin

I am working in an Android project in Android Studio in MAC OS and I am facing a problem when trying to save(and then insert) data from a register form in database.
I do not understand which is the best way to save data in database.
I have installed MySQL Workbench and XAMPP with PHPMyAdmin but I do not know how it goes in Android.Because when I have programmed Java in Netbeans there was simple ,just adding a '.jar' file for sql and creating the tables and procedures in MySQL and then calling those procedures in Java code?

Comment: Google for a SQLite Android tutorial

Answer (score 0):

**Android Application cannot directly connect to Remote Database.**

If you want to save something in mobile, you can use SQLite.
But if you want to use MySQL/ SQL Server, you need to expose those tables via REST API.

Create an API Service, which has access to those tables, and write a REST API to perform CRUD operations on Remote Database.
Mobile will call API to perform Remote DB operations on its behalf.

Comment: Technically that's not true. I've used some java library before that allowed for connection to MSSQL database. Can't remeber which one it was though. But of course that's not really a safe way of doing it since you could easily decompile apk file and find a connection.